# Encrypt MySQL data

Tags: mysql, encryption

How can I make my database more safe?

I know that I can:

1. Restrict access to mysql server
2. Create role with specific privileges
3. Encrypt filesystem
4. Use built-in MySQL encryption algorithms
5. Before I put data to database, I can hash specific columns, like email, address etc.

Is there anything more what I could to use to make data in mysql database more safe?

Comment: if you use the mysql build in algorithms, you prevents that DBA can read the data and also the DUMPS are also crypt and nobody else can restore and see the data. it take only ca. 10% of the performace

Comment: What about queries (SELECT, INSERT, etc.)? Could be there any problem with it?

Comment: no there are no problem. the only problem !! - if you lose your certificate or key you also cant restore a backup. read this: https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/table-and-tablespace-encryption-mariadb-101